# How to find the position of the smaller element in the list?

Tags: list-manipulation, searching

```
x = {4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7}
y = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9}
```

There are two lists x and y. How to find out these positions of the elements in list x are smaller than those in corresponding list y and get the following results:

```
{2, 3, 6}
```

Comment: Just for fun: `SparseArray[Ramp[y-x]]["NonzeroPositions"]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Flatten@Position[Negative[x - y], True]
```

Also possible:

```
Flatten@Position[x - y, _?(# < 0 &)]
```

or, as suggested by J.M.,

```
Flatten[Position[x - y, _?Negative]]
```

Comment: +1, nice use of `Negative`!

Comment: @corey979 Thanks, I wonder why it is not called `NegativeQ` rather than `Negative` btw... !

Comment: @anders, because `Negative[]` and similar functions don't have to immediately evaluate to `True`/`False` (while `*Q[]` functions do so), which makes them usable in assumptions like `Assuming[Negative[x], Simplify[UnitStep[x]]]`. (On that note, you can do your last one as `Flatten[Position[x - y, _?Negative]]`)

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 10):

```
Flatten @ Position[Less @@@ Transpose[{x, y}], True]
```

Comment: Equivalently: `Flatten[Position[Thread[x < y], True]]`

Answer (score 9):

```
PositionIndex[Sign[x - y]] @ -1
```

> {2, 3, 6}

Also

```
PositionIndex[UnitStep[x - y]] @ 0 (* thanks: J.M. *)
```

> {2, 3, 6}

```
PositionIndex[Negative[x - y]] @ True (* thanks: anderstood *)
```

> {2, 3, 6}

```
PositionIndex[Thread[x < y]]@True
```

> {2, 3, 6}

If you prefer to have `{}` (rather than `Missing["KeyAbsent", _]`) as output when no  positions satisfy the condition, you can use

```
Lookup[PositionIndex[Sign[x - y]], -1, {}]
Lookup[PositionIndex[UnitStep[x - y]], 0, {}]
Lookup[PositionIndex[Negative[x - y]], True, {}]
Lookup[PositionIndex[Thread[x < y]], True, {}]
```

for the four approaces above.

Comment: Another equivalent for the first: `Lookup[PositionIndex[UnitStep[x - y]], 0]`.

Comment: Also:  `PositionIndex[Negative[x - y]][True]`

Comment: Thank you both J.M. and @anderstood. I added your suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `MapIndexed`:**

```
x = {4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7};
y = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9};

MapIndexed[If[Less @@ #1, First@#2, Nothing] &, Transpose@{x, y}]
```

---

**Using `Inner`:**

```
Inner[Less, x, y, List] // Position[True] // Map[First]
```

---

*Result:*

> {2, 3, 6}

Answer (score 4):

Using `Position` and `Condition`:

```
Sequence @@@ Position[Thread[{x, y}], {x_, y_} /; x < y]

(*{2, 3, 6}*)
```

Or using `SubsetPosition` and `Select`:

```
First@SubsetPosition[#, Select[#, Less @@ # &]] &@Thread[{x, y}]

(*{2, 3, 6}*)
```

Another way using `Pick` and Thread`:

```
Keys@Pick[Thread[Range@Length@# -> #] &@#, Less @@@ #] &@Thread[{x, y}]

(*{2, 3, 6}*)
```

Comment: This use of `SubsetPosition` is new to me. Very useful. Already upvoted

Answer (score 4):

```
x = {4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7};
y = {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9};
```

Using `SequencePosition`

```
First /@ SequencePosition[Transpose[{x, y}], {a_} /; Less @@ a]
```

{2, 3, 6}

Using `MapThread`

```
First /@ Position[True] @ MapThread[Less, {x, y}]
```

{2, 3, 6}

Answer (score 3):

```
{4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7} - {1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 9} // MapIndexed[
    If[# < 0,
        First @ #2
        ,
        Nothing
    ]&
]
```